# Agregar varios valores a un textarea desde un DropDownList

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Como están, tengo una lista de enfermedades que se muestra en mi DropDownList y al seleccionarla se carga en el textarea, hasta ahí sin problemas; pero si vuelvo a seleccionar otra enfermedad se reemplaza en el Textarea y yo deseo que se agregue la nueva enfermedad seleccionada, espero puedan ayudarme

```js
$(document).on('change', '#idenfermedad', function (event) {
            $('#diagnos').val($("#idenfermedad option:selected").text());
        });
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="diagnostico" class="control-label"></label>                
                @Html.DropDownList("idenfermedad", listaEnfermedad, new { @class = "form form control" })
                <textarea asp-for="diagnostico" class="form-control col-md-12" rows="7" id="diagnos"></textarea>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```javascript
$(document).on('change', '#idenfermedad', function (event) {
  let valor_anterior = $('#diagnos').val()
  $('#diagnos').val(valor_anterior + ' ' + $("#idenfermedad option:selected").text());
});
```

y en el espacio vacio que he puesto de separación pon lo que quieras en su lugar, quizás un `\n` para que te salte la línea.

Comment: si funciona, muchas gracias